# Getting a page-curl transparent image to work with a solid background color

Tags: html, background-image, css

I have a small png with a transparent area I want to act as the bottom-right hand corner of a solid color div, but I can't seem to come up with an elegant way of doing this with css.

**my current css:**

```
div.example {
  border-radius: 9px;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: url(bottom-right-corner-peel.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right bottom;
}
```

The problem with the above code is that the background color of the div (`#fff`) shows through the transparent part of the png, ruining the effect.  I can think of a couple extremely hacky approaches to fix this (for example - creating another div (or using `::after`) to put an element below div in question, and use some tricks to make that work, but there must be a better way, right?

---

**View the [revised] Demo:**

> http://jsbin.com/abacey/8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution to your problem: http://jsfiddle.net/promatik/uZFpZ/

I've added a `#content-bottom` next to `#content`:

```
<div id="content">
    <h1>Corner Peel Demo</h1>
</div>
<div id="content-bottom">
    <div id="content-space"></div>
    <div id="content-corner"></div>
</div>
```

And added this in CSS:

```
div#content{
    ...
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
}
div#content-bottom {
    height: 30px;
    position: relative;
}
div#content-space {
    height: 27px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 9px;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-right: 42px;
}

div#content-corner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    height: 27px;
    width: 42px;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,...');
}
```

Comment: Well, sorry to put you through all this, but I think I wasn't specific enough in my post/example; the background of the page is actually not a solid color, but a textured image, so this approach wouldn't work.  If my background *was* solid, than I should just have the png not be transparent, and have that color in its background.

Comment: Another similar (and simpler) approach to yours would be instead of the div, to just use an <img> tag with a solid background applied - positioned absolutely in the bottom right. (but this still doesn't solve my specific problem)

Comment: beautiful - this looks great, thanks.  (and jsfiddle is back up, woohoo).  I'll give you the check-mark in a min (as soon as I understand this approach)

Answer (score 1):

My Ideas is to use the png to cover up the entire corner of the div.
Lets assume your png is 40x40px and the upper left part is white while the lower part is transparent.
You can use

```
border-bottom-right-radius: 40px;
```

to "cut off" the corner of the div. Therefore you have the background image visible. Now you lay your png over it to cover up the ugly round corner.

http://jsfiddle.net/Xd8CD/
(needs a better png...)

Comment: hmmm, I sort-of tried this already, but maybe you're onto something.  Gimme a min to demo this a bit more.

Comment: +1, cause it looks like this approach _will_ work, but only if I get my corner image to be a square (so I have to get my designer friend to make an update) Man, I really need to learn photoshop

Comment: In your example you will have to adjust the png to cover up the large rounded corner. The advatage over Tonis method is that the additional div cannot have content in it and it messes up all height calculations  based on percentages.

Comment: yea, I think your answer is preferable since it allows the markup to be nice, clean, and semantic.  I personally would use `:after` instead of the extra div - as in [this fork of your jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xd8CD/1/).  `::after` doesn't work in IE<8, but heck, they don't need the pretty corner.